# Triggering Fancy select after ajax content is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a case where I am dynamically populating a `select` tag options every time an ajax call happens successfully.

I am using [FancySelect](https://github.com/paulstraw/FancySelect).

My append code looks something like this:

```
success:function(data){

$("#subcategory-filter").html('<option value="" disabled selected>Select Sub-Category...</option>'); 

$("#subcategory-filter").append('<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>');

}
```

But I want to trigger [fancyselect](https://github.com/paulstraw/FancySelect) after the select tag is populated. I am trying to trigger the fancyselect right after the `append` function but that does not seem to work.

```
$('#subcategory-filter').fancySelect();
```

What I also tried is: udpate the fancyselect, as per the [documentation](https://github.com/paulstraw/FancySelect#updating-options).

```
$("#subcategory-filter").trigger('update.fs');
```

I have also tried `setTimeout` after the `append` function just to give some time for it to populate and then trigger the update but that too does not work.

May I know what would be the correct way to trigger `fancyselect` in my case.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Assuming no errors thrown in browser console there is no other obvious reason from what is stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really tell without inspecting the code more closely but, you could try:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
// Try to trigger fancyselect here
});
```

Hope it helps...